# When a Synchronized method is executed in a Java class, which Object is getting locked?

Tags: java, multithreading

When a Synchronized method is executed in a Java class, which Object is getting locked ?

Comment: class itself (`Class<?>` object)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because this question is not about a programming problem.  I.e., The question doesn't contain any example of code that the OP has written, and it doesn't ask why the code fails to meet the OP's expectations.

Answer (score 2):

For a static method, the class is locked

```
class A { 
    static synchronized void method() {
```

is like, though not exactly the same as

```
class A { 
    static void method() {
        synchronized(A.class) {
```

In this case- if one Thread is already executing this method, then no other Thread can invoke this method.

For an instance method, the instance is locked.

```
class A { 
    synchronized void method() {
```

is much the same as

```
class A { 
    void method() {
        synchronized(this) {
```

In this case- if there are different instance objects are initialized then one Thread per instance can enter into this execution block.

Note: it is a common misconception that there is a lock in the method or that the method is locked.  This is not the case and there is in fact no standard way to do this.

Comment: if you did manage to understand the question, could you edit it so it becomes clearer

Comment: @SleimanJneidi The question is clear enough, if this is the answer you were looking for.  I don't downvote often but some people downvote questions which they see as really basic Java that you should know.

Comment: You say your second example is "not exactly the same" as your first,  but is there any _practical_ difference between a `synchronized` instance method and an instance method whose entire body is a single `synchronized(this)` statement?  By "practical difference", I don't mean something you could tell by examining the byte codes; I mean, Is there any pure Java unit test you could write that would expose the difference between the two cases.

Comment: @PeterLawrey but don't we need encourage beginners to do their basic research before they post something, by answering them we aren't helping them IMO.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I would agree re basic research however this question is one of the ones I remember wondering myself along time ago.

Comment: great answer!!!